# Partition of unity on a manifold with a non-vanishing global vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose $M$ is manifold with a global non-vanishing vector field $X$.

Let $\{U\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be a locally finite covering of $M$ such that for each $\alpha$ and $p\in U_{\alpha}$ the maximal integral curve of $X$ containing $p$ is contained in $U_{\alpha.}$ Is it possible to find a partition of unity $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ subordinate to the covering such that $X(\phi_{\alpha})=0,$ for all $\alpha\in I$?

Comment: no - take $M=\mathbb R$, $X=d/dx$, then $\phi_\alpha$'s would have to be constant functions

Comment: Yes, that's true. I have to modify my question somewhat. The open sets in the covering can be assumed to contain the integral curves of $X$. I'll try to make this more precise.

Comment: The counterexample of user8268 still work. Just take $X$ to be any non-zero vector fields on $\mathbb R$. The condition on $U_\alpha$ does not matter. $X(\phi_\alpha) = 9$ implies that $\phi_\alpha$ is constant anyway.

Comment: I don't need the support of $\phi_\alpha$ to be compact. So in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ the covering would have to be $\{\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\phi$ could be taken to be identically $1.$ So this does not give a counter example.

Comment: From your above comment it seems that you can choose your open cover? (You will need to notify me by writing @Myusername in the comment)